# Custom Array-like getter on ES6 class

Tags: javascript, arrays, class, constructor, ecmascript-6

I want to create an `Class`, which is also a wrapper around a regular `Array`, however I want some custom behaviour to happen when referencing the items on the instance of the class via their index.

To demo what I want to achieve:

```
class Custom {
    constructor (arr) {
        this.arr = arr;
    }
    method (str) {
        this.arr.forEach(item => {
            console.log(`${item} ${str}`);
        })
    }
    [Magic.here] () {
        // this part should invoke the constructor of this class with a single item of the array passed into it as an array of one as argument.
    }
}

let c = new Custom(['something', 'other thing', 'hello?']);

c[1].method('exists?') // -> other thing exists?
```

Now, I am not entirely sure that it is possible. I did manage to come up with not-too-great solutions of my own, by `extend`ing `Array`. `Proxy` also came into my mind, but couldn't get a working solution down.

Is it even possible and if so, what is the best way?

Comment: You seem to be mixing up wrappers around the array with wrappers around the elements. Will it be `c.method()` or `c[1].method()`? They definitely should have distinct classes.

Comment: If you read the commend inside the `[Magic.here]` bit of my code demo, you'll realise that I do want to invoke the constructor from the getter, like so: `c[0]` returns a `new Custom(this.arr[0])` basically, on which `method` can then be invoked separately.

Comment: Yes, but from the parameter names of the constructor and the example invokcation with the array I realise that `Custom` is the constructor of the array wrapper, not the one for elements to be invoked from the getter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for a proxy:

```
const isArrayIndex = str => (str >>> 0) + '' === str && str < 4294967295;
const arrayCustomizer = {
    get(target, property, receiver) {
        var el = Reflect.get(target, property, receiver);
        if (isArrayIndex(property) && el != null)
            el = new Custom(el);
        return el;
    }
}
class Custom {
    constructor(v) {
        this.value = v;
    }
    valueOf() {
        return this.value;
    }
    method(arg) {
        console.log(this.value + " " + arg.replace("?", "!"));
    }
}

let c = new Proxy(['something', 'other thing', 'hello?'], arrayCustomizer);
c[1].method('exists?')
```

Comment: Hey! I managed to abstract away your method and got a working example, however... When I create that `Proxy` it hides away all the class properties from the main instance, like `c.method()` will no longer exist. My knowledge about `Proxy` at the moment is limited, but I'll accept your answer and if you can give me a solution to the above as well, I'll be forever grateful. :)

Comment: `c` is just an array, it never had a `.method` property (and I don't see why it would need to). Only its elements are instances of `Custom`.

Answer (score 1):

[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is indeed what you're looking for. Take a look at this example:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
const proxy = new Proxy(array, {
  get(target, property) {
    console.log(`Proxy get trap, property ${property}`);
    return Reflect.get(target, property);
  },
});

proxy[1]; // logs "Proxy get trap, property 1"
```

Whatever you return in the `get` trap will be the result of evaluating `proxy[index]`, so for example instead of returning `Reflect.get(target, property)` you could return some object.

Answer (score 1):

After reading these answers and digging some more I managed to come up with a full solution, using `Proxy`. I am posting this here, in case someone on the internet comes up with a crazy idea like mine and wants an easy solution.

I annotated the code for a simple explanation:

```js
/**
 * The class I want to proxy on
 */

class Random {
  constructor (arr) {this.arr=arr}
  method () {this.arr.forEach(el=>{console.log(el)})}
}

// Creating a separate function for initializing the class. This will have to be used instead of the regular class' constructor if we want to use the proxy as well.

function init (arr) {
  // Creating a new instance of random class based on arr, passing it into proxy
  var p = new Proxy(new Random(arr), {
    // Modifying the get function on handler
    get: function (target, name) {
      // Checking if the name is a numeric reference
      if (typeof name === 'string' && /^-?\d+$/.test(name)) {
        // ... it is, so we call init with the selected item in the array on our class object
        let r = init([target.arr[name]]);
        // finally we return the new proxy from init
        return r;
      }
      else {
        // otherwise we are looking at a direct reference, maybe to a method or scope variable, like random.method()
        return target[name]
      }
    }
  })
  // we return the proxy
  return p;
}

let random = init(['hello', 'amazing', 'world'])

console.log(random[0]); // proxy reference to array of hello
console.log(random[1]); // proxy reference to array of amazing

random.method(); // logs out all 3 items of array
random[2].method(); // logs out third item
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Happy coding :)